# VAE : How is likelihood $p(x|z)$ defined?

Tags: likelihood, autoencoders, variational-bayes, variational-inference

Disclaimer : not a strong background in Bayesian statistics.

I gather from questions such as [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/351505/why-do-variational-bayes-methods-assume-that-the-likelihood-pxz-is-tractabl?rq=1) and [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/314413/why-is-pxz-tractable-but-pzx-intractable/314441#314441) that in the context of VAEs, we suppose that we know the (form of the ?) prior $p(z)$ and the likelihood $p(x|z)$. What we don't know is the posterior $p(z|x)$ and the marginal $p(x)$, the whole point of the VAE training process being to approximate them. However, I **don't understand how we define the likelihood $p(x|z)$ and what form does it usually take**.

Intuitively, I'd think that we would set it as some Gaussian for it be easily conjugable with the prior, to facilitate the computation of the posterior. Indeed, [Wikipedia](https://(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evidence_lower_bound#Motivation)) seems to say that $p(x|z)$ is usually defined as a Normal distribution :

> - First, define a simple distribution $p(z)$ over a latent random variable $Z$. Usually a normal distribution or a uniform distribution
>   suffices.
> - Next, define a family of complicated functions $f_{\theta }$ (such as a deep neural network) parametrized by $\theta$ .
> - Finally, define a way to convert any $f_{\theta }(z)$ into a simple distribution over the observable random variable $X$. For example, let
>   $f_{\theta }(z)=(f_{1}(z),f_{2}(z))$ have two outputs, then we can
>   define the corresponding distribution over $X$ to be the normal
>   distribution $N(f_{1}(z),e^{f_{2}(z)})$.

But I thought that this was this "implictly parametrized distribution" "trick" was how we set $p(z|x)$ : As shown in the image below, it is $z$ which is sampled from a Normal distribution parametrized by $x$. In this image, $p(x|z)$ is defined as the function learned by a neural network, which is certainly not a "simple" function.

[image]
(image is from [here](https://lilianweng.github.io/posts/2018-08-12-vae/))

Answer (score 2):

The "whole point of the VAE training process" is to find an approximation to $p(z|x)$ [find the encoder] and to maximize $p(x|z)$ given the data [find the decoder].

In the original paper, they give 2 possibilities for the likelihood - either a Gaussian for continuous data, or Bernoulli for discrete data. E.g., Gaussian for images with a range of pixel value, and Bernoulli for 1-bit images (pixel is either black or white). [In practice you can also use Binary Cross Entropy (the negative log likelihood of Bernoulli distribution) also on grayscale images.]

As mentioned in appendix:
[image]

The "reparameterization trick" is used in the encoder, on $q(z|x)$, it's not related to the way you transform $z$ into $p(x|z)$. Both Gaussian and Bernoulli are simple **distributions**. Not functions. The way you get to their parameters can be very complex.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your output domain

- It can be a Multivariate Gaussian
  $$p(x|z) \sim \mathcal{N}(z, \mu_\phi(z),\Sigma_\phi(z))$$
- For images, you can also take a categorical distribution over the pixel values.
  $$p(x|z) \sim \text{Categorical}(x|\phi(z))$$
  In practice, this translates to a neural network where you take the softmax over the pixel values.

You can then learn the parameterization $\phi$ of $p_\phi(x|z)$ by MLE, i.e. maximizing
$$\mathbb{E}_{z \sim q_\theta(z)}[\log p_\phi(x|z)]$$

> Indeed, Wikipedia seems to say that p(x|z)
> is usually defined as a Normal distribution

I think Wikipedia is talking about the parameterization of $q(z|x)$ in the passage you cited. $f_1(z)$ computes $\mu_\theta$ and $f_2(z)$ computes $\log \Sigma_\theta$.
This is the distribution from where you sample $z \sim \mathcal{N}(z,\mu_\phi,\Sigma^2_\phi)$, which you then feed into the decoder.

You can find a detailed description of variational autoencoders [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/321841/what-are-variational-autoencoders-and-to-what-learning-tasks-are-they-used/328181#328181)